# Cakephp ACL deny all admin actions

Tags: php, cakephp

i am using ACL now i want to be able to deny a certain group access to any `admin_action`

is there a fast way of doing this?

```
$group->id = 2;
$this->Acl->deny($group, 'admin');

$group->id = 2;
$this->Acl->deny($group, 'controller/admin');
```

The above two examples doesnt seem to work.

example url i want my users to avoid:

```
http://mydomain.com/cake/index.php/admin/clients/pending
```

what i want to do is restrict access to anything named admin/

Answer (score 0):

try `$this->Acl->deny( array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => '2' ), 'controller/admin' );`

Comment: Well the admin is not a model nor controller it is just like the admin section aka: www.yourdomain.com/cake/index.php/admin/controller/action

Will the above code work for this?

Comment: just tested the above sadly this had no effect.

Comment: depending on your structure, the second param should be something like 'admin/controller/action' or 'controller/action'

Comment: cakePHP permission is bottom to top...so if you have this permission tree admin->clients->pending, and you deny access to admin, without expressly denying access to admin's children, then users would still have access to clients, and pending. you'd need to start your denial from the child, then work your way up

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this using ACL. You have so set the permission one action per time.

But you can overwrite isAuthorized function in AppController

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if (isset($user['group']) && $user['group'] === 1) {
        ... check if action param is set and in case return true otherwise return false....

    }
    return parent::isAuthrized($user);
}
```